# Mercurial doesn't see files of its subrepos

Tags: mercurial

We want to create several hg repos
1. /var - big one which is supposed to include files of all nested repos
2. subrepos like /var/repo1 /var/repo2

But the problem is that main hg repo in (/var folder) cannot see new or modified files of subrepos in /var/repo1 /var/repo2. Is there any way to configure main repository so that it can see file modifications of subrepos?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-S` flag to recurse into subrepositories, but it doesn't work for all commands. This is by design, nested repositories should be operated separately, eg. commit in the main repo with the `-S` switch will actually make separate commit for each nested repository but with same message.

`hg status -S`  displays all changes including subrepos.

`hg commit -S`  commits all changes in this and all nested repositories that have changes.